# Instead of glass, a different material is rendered

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, glass

Hello hope you can help me.
I'm working on an archviz scene and for some reason glass material is not rendering. In render preview it does work but on final rendering it doesn`t.
Does anyone has any ideas?
Thanks in advance,

[image: render preview]
[image: render region final render]
[image: node setup]

Comment: Is it possible that there is a mesh there that is disabled for preview but enabled for rendering?